# Geoserver netCDF output missing classes

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

I downloaded the latest stable release (2.7.1.1) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/. It starts with the integrated jetty and works fine so far.

So I wanted to configure netCDF output for WCS Layers and downloaded the netCDF plugins from here: http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.7.x/community-latest/

However starting the server after installing them to geoserver/libs results in:

`java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:138)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:159)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/FileSetManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.FileSetManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
2015-07-20 17:44:55.798::WARN:  failed ContextHandlerCollection@54a7079e
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:138)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:159)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/FileSetManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.FileSetManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
2015-07-20 17:44:55.802::INFO:  Opened /usr/share/geoserver/logs/2015_07_20.request.log
2015-07-20 17:44:55.802::WARN:  failed HandlerCollection@4b8ee4de
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:138)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:159)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/FileSetManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.FileSetManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
2015-07-20 17:44:55.803::WARN:  Error starting handlers
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:138)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:159)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/FileSetManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.FileSetManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more`

Comment: does it still happen with the 2.7.x nightly build?

Comment: Same result. I also have the same result if I use the 2.5.5.1 release and the corresponding plugins.

Comment: `Error loading class [org.geoserver.wcs.responses.NetCDFCoverageResponseDelegate] for bean with name 'netcdfCoverageResponseDelegate' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/geoserver/lib/gs-netcdf-out-2.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geoserver/wcs/responses/CoverageResponseDelegate` comes when only installing netCDF plugin and not the netCDF out plugin. Same for me on all versions I tried.

Comment: And the next one if i deploy a war in tomcat 7:
`Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'netcdfStorePanel' defined in URL xxx: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'factoryClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFFormat]`

Comment: The problem still exists in 2.14.1 under Windows with Jetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually only exists in the standalone installable version of geoserver. Deploying the war on tomcat and installing the libs gives no problems.

Comment: The problem is still existing in build 2.8.3 in standalone mode

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the issue would happen if the netcdf output plugin is installed without installing also the netcdf plugin (the input one). Installing the input plugin should solve the issue.

You might want to open a ticket about it at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary